# C# how to identify a guest account?

Tags: c#, user-accounts

In my c# winForm application I have to recognize if a guest account is running the application.
Any idea?

Answer (score 10):

You can check the [`IsGuest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.isguest.aspx) property of the current `WindowsIdentity`:

```
if (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsGuest)
{
    // it's a guest account
}
```